# How to suppress the output of a library function

Tags: c

I wish to suppress the default output of the function **smbc_opendir()**, and print only using printf.

gcc filename.c -lsmbclient

```
#include <libsmbclient.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void auth_fn()
{

}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])   
{ 
  int dirHandle;
  if(smbc_init(auth_fn,  10)) /* Initialize things */
  {
     return 0;
  }
  dirHandle= smbc_opendir(argv[1]);    /* Argument is smb://<ip-address>/ */
  /* Just display value of dirHandle in output and nothing else */
  printf("%d",dirHandle);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `smbc_opendir` is writing to `stderr` then you could temporarily redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` and then restore it afterwards.

Comment: OK - the same principle applies to `stdout`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try debug level 0, it shall log only critical errors: `smbc_init(auth_fn, 0)`

Comment: Thanks, it perfectly did what i wanted! You seem to know about the libsmbclient. It is not threadsafe, is it still possible anyways to run each instance of smbc_opendir() in a separate thread!

Comment: @adnankamili As far as I know it's not designed to be thread-safe. At least it wasn't two or three years ago (I didn't use it for a long time).

Comment: @adnankamili So I think - no, you cannot use it in MT environment.

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect the stdout or the stderr with something such as:

```
stderr = freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr );
```

and then you call smbc_opendir.

Comment: How to restore the output back to stdout